# how to add a specific value to a column iteratively in python

Tags: python, loops

I have a line that have different columns and for one particular column (column 2) i want to add some values from another column (column 12 except 0) iteratively. I was able to do it for the first one but not for the rest of the columns. Here is an example of the line

```
A01     5729384 5730870 Bra1000071      117     -       5729384 5730870 255,0,0 4       281,252,145,229 0,380,1030,1257
```

And here is the desired output

```
A01     5729764 5730870 Bra1000071      117     -       5729384 5730870 255,0,0 4       281,252,145,229 0,380,1030,1257
A01     5730794 5730870 Bra1000071      117     -       5729384 5730870 255,0,0 4       281,252,145,229 0,380,1030,1257
A01     5732051 5730870 Bra1000071      117     -       5729384 5730870 255,0,0 4       281,252,145,229 0,380,1030,1257
```

Here is my psuedocode

```
with open('velvet.test.bed') as fh_in:
    for line in fh_in:
        line = line.strip().split()
        x1 = line[11].split(',')
        print x1
        for j in x1:
            print j
            if j!= "0":
                next
                y1 = int(line[1]) + int(j)
                test = line[0], " " + str(y1) + " " + " ".join(line[2:])
                print test
```

Here is the output i am getting...

```
A01 5729764 5730870 Bra1000071 117 - 5729384 5730870 255,0,0 4 281,252,145,229 0,380,1030,1257
A01 5730414 5730870 Bra1000071 117 - 5729384 5730870 255,0,0 4 281,252,145,229 0,380,1030,1257
A01 5730641 5730870 Bra1000071 117 - 5729384 5730870 255,0,0 4 281,252,145,229 0,380,1030,1257
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you go:

```
>>> a = "A01     5729384 5730870 Bra1000071      117     -       5729384 5730870 255,0,0 4       281,252,145,229 0,380,1030,1257"
>>> a = a.split()
>>> add_num = list(map(int,a[-1].split(',')[1:]))   #split with whitespace and taken last element, removed 0 and using map to convert them to int
>>> for i in range(len(add_num)):
...     print(" ".join([b[0]] + [str(int(b[1])+sum(add_num[:i+1]))] + b[2:]))
... 
A01 5729764 5730870 Bra1000071 117 - 5729384 5730870 255,0,0 4 281,252,145,229 0,380,1030,1257
A01 5730794 5730870 Bra1000071 117 - 5729384 5730870 255,0,0 4 281,252,145,229 0,380,1030,1257 
A01 5732051 5730870 Bra1000071 117 - 5729384 5730870 255,0,0 4 281,252,145,229 0,380,1030,1257
```

your code will look like:

```
f = open('file')
for a in f:
    a = a.split()
    add_num = list(map(int,a[-1].split(',')[1:]))
    for i in range(len(add_num)):
        print(" ".join([b[0]] + [str(int(b[1])+sum(add_num[:i+1]))] + b[2:]))
```